# Exact meaning of ou bien

Tags: grammaire, sens

*Bien* means well or good. But I have seen in some cases these two meanings do not fit well. For example, in "Étant donnée une F, ou bien elle est formée d'une relation de base finie, ou bien...", "ou bien" translated to "or well" does not sound good.

So I wonder what is the exact meaning of *bien* above.

Comment: ***Bien*** has no independent meaning in the ***ou bien*** set phrase.  On the other hand, ***bien*** has its own meaning in the now deleted *...atteint **bien** A* example, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“*Ou bien*” is a set phrase which is practically synonymous with “*ou*” or “*soit*”: the whole phrase “*ou bien*” means “or” (or “either” when it's in lead position). It is usually constructed like “*soit*”, i.e. it is present before the first alternative as well as between alternatives. The following are roughly equivalent and mean “[either] A or B”:

> A ou B
> A ou alors B   *(usually used when A and B are very long phrases)*
> A ou bien B
> ou bien A, ou bien B
> soit A soit B

There is a nuance in that “*soit*” is more likely to be an exclusive or, and “*ou bien*” a little more likely to be exclusive than “*ou*”. However, all the formulations can either be exclusive or inclusive. In math, “*ou*” is always exclusive, but in everyday language, it's often exclusive and “*et/ou*” can be used (mostly in writing) to indicate an inclusive or (and like “and/or” in English, not everyone likes it). “*Ou bien*” and “*soit*” are ambiguous even in math: they're usually exclusive but can be inclusive.

Comment: “Ou alors” seems also exclusive to me, especially in math

Comment: @JamesSilipo Like “ou”, it often is, but not always. Unlike “ou”, it can be exclusive in math.

Comment: “Ou alors” souds to me like “ou autrement” e.g. “Un anneau est intègre ou alors il ne l’est pas”

Comment: @hermes "Le nombre des y distincts atteint bien A." → “bien” means “indeed”. The meaning is unrelated. But please don't add unrelated questions to your existing questions.

Comment: No, "ou alors" is not exclusive. For example one could say "X ou Y ou alors Z". Example "Il viendra en voiture, ou en train, ou alors en avion."

Comment: @Jonathan sorry but in your second example, if he comes by plane, this excludes that he comes by car or train! Isn’t it?

Comment: You are right @James that was a bad example.

Comment: The word "alors" in "ou alors" often indicates a consequence. For example "Pars un peu plus tôt, ou alors tu seras en retard."

Comment: Le "ou" des mathématiciens est un "ou" inclusif : p∨q sera vraie lorsque p et q sont vraies toutes les deux. (https://www.auto-math.be/public/7/module/4/theorie/5) // In mathematics, the word “or” means “one or the other or both”. ... In other words, the statement is only false if “it will rain” is false and “it will snow” is also false. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=or+in+mathematics

Comment: @LPH Dans une formule mathématique, oui : les mathématiciens n'utilisent pratiquement jamais le ou exclusif. Mais dans un **texte** mathématique, ce n'est pas toujours le cas.

Comment: Ce qui constitue vraiment la mathématique ce sont les axiomes, les définitions, les théorèmes, et les preuves ; dans cette partie le connecteur est inclusif ; dans une discussion informelle qui sert à présenter ces 4 éléments (ce que vous devez appeler le texte) il n'est pas possible d'utiliser « ou » avec une autre convention parce que l'on ne s'y retrouverait plus; pour un rare « ou » exclusif on utilise "soit…soit" ((in)formel) et la négation d'une équivalence (très formel); référence personnelle, pour tout travail mathématique, ou inclusif : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJfYP.jpg

Comment: @LPH Tu confonds les mathématiques (hors sujet ici) et le langage utilisé par les mathématiciens pour faire des mathématiques (dont il est question ici lorsque ce langage est un dialecte du français).

Comment: I l n'est jamais question de ces dialectes, où que ce soit, ni en français , ni en anglais; dans les deux cas lorsque la question est posée (Quel connecteur est celui que l'on utilise en mathématiques ?) la réponse est « Le connecteur inclusif ». Trois références que j'ai fourni montrent cela et on peut en trouver d'autres.